# SQL Server : join 2 queries, performance issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

I have two (rather complex) functions which both return a table;

```
(SELECT Id, x, y FROM fnGetXY(3)) (execution takes +/- 5 sec)

(SELECT Id, a, b FROM fnGetAB(3)) (execution takes +/- 15 sec)
```

I want to combine the result;

```
SELECT X.Id, x, y, a, b FROM 
(
 (SELECT Id, x, y FROM fnGetXY(3)) X
 JOIN (SELECT Id, a, b FROM fnGetAB(3)) Y ON X.Id=Y.Id
)
```

The result is correct, however this does not take the expected +/- 20-25 seconds, but 90 seconds.

Is there any way I can force a combination of the results of the two queries in a way that consumes maximum slightly more than the sum of each?

**[Update]**

1. #temp; As this is part of a function, a #temp table is not an option unfortunately.
2. I have tried LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN with no result, **but** it appears that **FULL OUTER JOIN** solves this case..

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the solution is to save the intermediate results into #temp tables and then join the results:

```
select Id, x, y
into #t1
from fnGetXY(3)

select Id, a, b 
into #t2
from fnGetAB(3)

SELECT #t1.Id, x, y, a, b 
FROM #t1
INNER JOIN #t2 on #t1.id = #t2.id
```

SQL Server optimizer doesn't like dealing with functions very much (except the inline TVFs).

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you add the returned result sets into temp tables ??

Comment: Out of experience :) Seriously, I've had to deal with far too many performance problems caused by TVFs and this approach seemed to help.

Comment: I'm curious as well. I've found that quite often, when dealing with very large TB-size databases, using temp tables to store midresults can be an order of magnitude faster than just putting it all together at once. I can understand the execution planner getting confused with an huge number of hash joins etc, but it's still counterintuitive with the idea that typically DB's are at their best if they have access to the whole data at once, as opposed to the looping based approach on basic Java / C# etc for instance. This is like a small exception to that.

Comment: I would love to find out more about this, what exactly is going on under the covers, because what I can see is, in your suggested solution sql server will have to execute two functions separately just as it would have to do as in my suggested solution and then insert them results into a temp table and than join them, I just cant get me head around the idea that how sql server can perform better by doing more work :S

Comment: Well a typical example I just dealt with a few weeks back was a largeish 20-table join query where one table column was filtered for 5 specific values. Using IN ("5 values here") would run indefinitely. Instead, running the same query 5 times for each individual value, and storing them all into a temp table, took but a few minutes. And that's just ONE example, out of dozens by now.

Comment: @Kahn The case you're describing is somewhat different, and has to do with cardinality estimates. They can go wrong and multiply from operator to operator, but if you keep intermediate results in a temp table then they're not estimates any more. Also, a search space for a decent execution plan is smaller if you divide. About the INs -- they're actually ORs under the covers, and with a limited IN lists it's almost always better to refactor into UNION ALLs

Comment: @M.Ali Neither of us actually saw the execution plans, so it's pure speculation, but my thinking is that in your answer the engine is implicitly doing same as I did explicitly, with the difference that there is no more guesswork about the results of the functions.

Comment: You are right about its being all speculation with actually looking at the execution plan, The reason I raised this question because I was seriously curious that how sql server can do more work faster maybe there is some wisdom to that, It was purely an educational question rather than criticism for the sake of criticism :) I will do some research on this and will report back if I find some more information on this.

Comment: @M.Ali Please do, there is my personal email address in the profile to reach me offline.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to JOIN these two functions as you would join two table, I think these sub-queries are just an overkill of a fairly simple query. Try something like ....

```
SELECT t1.Id
     , t1.x
     , t1.y
     , t2.a 
     , t2.b 
FROM fnGetXY(3) t1 INNER JOIN fnGetAB(3) t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Comment: Hi, this is where I started and got the terrible performance issue. I hoped that the sub-queries would fool SQL Server, but no difference